# MS Access Many-Many Query/Form Assistance

Tags: ms-access, many-to-many

I have somewhat of a beginner-type question.

Could someone look at the below relationships and let me know why I can't get the following form/query to only show the unique Appointment letters? I have 143 appointment letters. I have 135 members. I have 585 records in the junction table. I know that I messed up the form source query (below), but how badly am I off? Your expertise is greatly appreciated.

Resources used:

- 3 Example databases
- 4 MS Access 2003/2010/2013 books
- 5 links:
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108525/ms-access-2010-query-pulls-same-records-multiple-times-sql-challenge
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473604/basic-many-to-many-sql-select-query
- [Querying a many to many relationship in access](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/146719/querying-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-access)
- [Help with Access many-to-many relationship (beginner)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/136130/help-with-access-many-to-many-relationship-beginner)
- [Query Multiple tables in MS Access](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51686/query-multiple-tables-in-ms-access)

Screenshot of Relationships:
[image: Screenshot of Relationships]

Form:
[image: Screenshot of Form]

Query:
[image: Screenshot of Query]

SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW tbl_apptltrs.*, jtbl_apptltrs_mbrs.*, tbl_mbrs.*
FROM tbl_mbrs INNER JOIN (
    tbl_apptltrs INNER JOIN jtbl_apptltrs_mbrs
    ON tbl_apptltrs.ApptLtrsID = jtbl_apptltrs_mbrs.LinkedApptLettersID)
ON tbl_mbrs.MembersID = jtbl_apptltrs_mbrs.LinkedMembersID;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having to do a little bit of psychic debugging here, but generally speaking, you should have the subform bound to a query that joins your junction table to the table of related records. The form inside the subform shouldn't know about the table in the left side of the relationship (tbl_apptltrs).

So the chain is something like this:

1. Main form bound to `tbl_apptltrs`.
2. Subform linked to main form via primary key of `tbl_appltrs` (e.g. parent form `ApptLtrsID` = subform `LinkedApptLettersID`).
3. Form inside subform bound to query that joins `jtbl_apptltrs_mbrs` to `tbl_mbrs` (`jtbl_apptltrs_mbrs.LinkedMemberID = tbl_mbrs.MemberID`).

Comment: I feel like an idiot. As soon as I performed step 1 (set Main form to have `tbl_apptltrs` as the Record Source) everything appears to be correct. I'll definitely clean up the subforms with more specifics (like what you did with steps 2 & 3) but I believe this fixed it. This is definitely a lot more simple than what I thought the answer was. Thank you!